# Unable to well understand Rsync with include and exclude patterns

Tags: rsync

First of all, I really read a lot about this topic (including [Rsync filter: copying one pattern only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503)), but I still don't understand, or I have a problem with my installation...

My structure "from" is something like this:

```
Windows
Users
  User1
    Documents
      doc1.txt
      doc2.txt
    AppData
    Downloads
  User2
    Documents
      doc3.txt
      doc4.txt
    AppData
    Downloads
```

I want to backup all Documents folders and subfolders from all users, but not AppData and Downloads structures.

On the destination I want:

```
Users
 User1
  Documents
   doc1.txt
   doc2.txt
 User2
  Documents
   doc3.txt
   doc4.txt
```

I did tried many patterns, but none are working well. Let's start with this one:

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --exclude="*/AppData" --exclude="*/Downloads" /source/Users /destination
```

What should I do to exclude AppData and Downloads folders and subfolders for each user ?

Thanks

There is another thread discussing almost the same thing (if I well understand it): 
[rsync with absolute paths and excluding subpaths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34787/rsync-with-absolute-paths-and-excluding-subpaths)

I adapted the answer to my situation, but the AppData and Downloads are still present on the destination path.

```
rsync -av --no-p  --include="*/" --include="*/Documents/**" --exclude="** /source/Users /destination
```

Comment: Try `**` instead of `*`.

Comment: `exclude="**/AppData"` gave me the same result. (by the way, I'm using rsync 3.1.1). I'm also quite confused this the usage of `*`. I even saw in some command lines  `test/***`...

Comment: `rsync -avr --exclude="AppData" --exclude="Downloads" /source/Users /destination`

Comment: @Costas What the hell! That simple ? It works as expected...Thanks. One more question: in this specific case, if I want to obtain the same result (copying Documents folders for all users), could I exclude everything but Documents ?

Comment: I think much easy to select `Documents` directly by `rsync -av /source/Users/User*/Downloads /destination`

Answer (score 2):

In many shell `*` do not include `/` symbol (rather than ahead `.`) (see **man 7 glob** and `globstar`|`dotglob` options in `shopt`) , so if you want to exclude *AppData* and *Downloads* you should provide full path from *source* (`--exclude="*/*/AppData" --exclude="*/*/Downloads"`) or just remain name only (`--exclude="AppData" --exclude="Downloads"`) if does not matter on which level directories is situated.

```
rsync -av --exclude="AppData" --exclude="Downloads" /source/Users /destination
```